# Second argument of the mapply inside function as a vector in R

Tags: r, list, vector, mapply

I know the title is a bit confusing, so sorry for it.
First some code to generate data we need :

```
ref_variables=LETTERS[1:10]
# Function to generate one dataset
generate_df=function(){
row=100
d0=seq(1:100)
for (i in seq_along(ref_variables)){
  dtemp=sample(seq(1:row),row,TRUE)
  d0=data.frame(d0,dtemp)
}
d0[,1]=NULL
names(d0)=ref_variables
return(d0)
}

# Generating a list of dataset
list_of_df=lapply(seq(1:100),function (x){
  generate_df()
} )

# Générating a list of vectors
df_vector=sample(ref_variables,3,FALSE)
for (i in seq(2,100)){
tmp=sample(ref_variables,3,FALSE)
df_vector=rbind(df_vector,tmp)
}
list_of_vector <- split(df_vector, seq(nrow(df_vector)))
```

Ok, so, I have a function some_function  which take a data.frame and a vector as arguments :

```
#Some function a data.frame and a vector as arguments
some_function=function(a_df,a_vector){
  return(a_df[,a_vector])
}
```

I got a list of data.frame and a list of vectors. So I want to map the data.frame to the vector according to their position  as arguments of some_function. Particularly I would like to run :

```
some_function(list_of_df[[1]],unlist(list_of_vector[[1]]))
some_function(list_of_df[[2]],unlist(list_of_vector[[2]]))
some_function(list_of_df[[3]],unlist(list_of_vector[[3]]))
and so on ...
```

So I decided to use mapply function with :

```
big_results=mapply(some_function,
                   list_of_df,
                   list_of_vector)
```

But, big_results is of length 300, although, I expected 100 only. And obviously, the results are not what I expected as well. Does anyone know what's going on here and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

We need to use either `Map`

```
r1 <- Map(function(x,y) x[,y], list_of_df, list_of_vector)
length(r1)
#[1] 100
```

Or `mapply` with `SIMPLIFY = FALSE`

```
r2 <- mapply(function(x,y) x[,y], list_of_df, list_of_vector, SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
length(r2)
#[1] 100
```

---

The `Map` is just a wrapper for `mapply` with the option `SIMPLIFY=FALSE`.  What happens is when the object dimensions are the same, it simplifies to a matrix for `mapply` as the default option is `SIMPLIFY = TRUE`

```
r3 <- mapply(function(x,y) x[,y], list_of_df, list_of_vector)
length(r3)
#[1] 300
```

The `length` of a `matrix` is the product of its dimensions, i.e.

```
m1 <- matrix(1:6, ncol=2)
length(m1)
#[1] 6
```

Comment: Waow awesome! Excuse me, I know I can make a search on Google but since you might be competent in it, can you tell me what is wrapper? I never been able to understand it.

Comment: @hansglick Just type `Map` on your console It will give `function (f, ...) 
{
    f <- match.fun(f)
    mapply(FUN = f, ..., SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
}`